PC to USB 3.2 transfer speed abysmally slow on Ubuntu
Firstly, I've scoured all related questions and there is no solution anywhere, I request you to not redirect me to questions I've most probably read 2-3 times already, unless you think it could genuinely help me, thank you.
I'm running a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a HP Probook G2 640 (Gnome 46.0). I have a 256 GB USB 3.2 SanDisk Pen Drive, and I've been trying to store data on it. As the title states, it has been excruciatingly slow. Trying to transfer just 7 GBs of data shows ~2 hours estimated time (using gcp, if i just use GUI then it's just as slow if not more). Transfer speeds start off at 50 MBps, but the very next instant it drops to 10, then 5, then it stabilizes at ~900kbps. If i try to stop the transfer and restart it (in gcp), the speed actually drops even lower, giving 50-60 kbps. I've tried formatting it many times, thinking that perhaps its current format is incompatible or something. So far, I've tried exFAT, FAT, NTFS, ext4, and unfortunately there has been no change. The slow speeds are maintained while using gcp, cp, and even just drag-dropping via Nautilus.
Tested it on Windows, it transferred a ~5GB Ubuntu ISO file within a minute. It's only when I switched to Ubuntu that I started having these problems. Also, this problem has persisted since Ubuntu 22.04, so I think it has nothing to do with 24.04.
Right now my pendrive is in ext4 format, and I ran a benchmark test on it. Here's the result.

As you can see, read speeds are good enough but the write speeds want to become one with the x axis.
My lsusb result :
brian@BrianProBook:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7053 Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 248a:8367 Maxxter Telink Wireless Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade

Seen many forums debating this same problem, never found a solution which works for me. Please help me with this, thank you.
P.S. Documents and PDFs upto 200mb get transferred very fast (average write speed 78mbps), but the things I actually want to transfer (multiple mp4 and mkv files which are more than 300mb in size each) are the ones giving me this issue.

I found rsync to be a bit faster. But flash drives are slow. Varies a lot by brand and a few new ones may be almost as fast as SSD. I have many larger flash drives, but a couple of years ago updated M.2 SSD to NVMe & put M.2 SSD in an USB adapter (~$25). So much faster, almost as fast as when internal SSD, I will not buy any more flash drives.  And have purchased another M.2 NVMe drive and adapter. I remember when flash drives were real expensive and before inflation, so M.2 drive & adapter is not that expensive.

The 256GB Sandisk USB claims 130MB/4MB Read/Write, so the 1 minute copy time for 5GB on Windows is out of line. With all the buffering going on, copy times are hard to measure without a blinking light on the target -- even the Linux "time" command will finish long before buffers get flushed. Real life it 1/2 to 1/3 of the advertised maxes (what you see on your write graph). It only gets (much) worse when buffers fill because of a slow target. How much mem do you have? How much is free when copying files > total mem? Does the whole system slow down?  Specific cases might be faster with tweaks.

I have also experienced a dramatic difference copying a large amount of data to a thumbdrive on 24.04 vs 22.04.  Since the author of this question has also experienced this change, it's time to consider submitting something as a bug to Ubuntu support.  My next step is try a copy of several GB to a thumb on 24.04 and 22.04 then reverse the thumb drives and again perform the copy.  Also in my case, the hardware is the same - Dell 7020 desktops with ubuntu xx.04 installed on a fresh hard drive. By the way my 32GB thumb drives are NTFS.

Already my testing confirms what was reported here and then some.  Transfer time on Ubuntu 22.04 was about 10 minutes.  On 24.04 it was Two hours and 7 minutes transferring the same data from a local directory to the same thumb drive, which was cleared prior to each run to insure uniform conditions.
